# Partial derivative of higher order without knowing the function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$. I want to compute $D_{1,2}f(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$. And I know that $D_{2}f(x,0)=x$. How can I continue? I don't know the function $f(x,y)$. Can I say $D_{1}(D_{2}f(x,0))$?

Comment: What is the Criterion of a function?

Comment: @BernardMasse Sorry English is not my first language. I edited it.